# efficient apply function to implement on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have create polarity score of all the reviews in dataframe. I am using vader library for this. I am using lamda function applying on dataframe to create polarity score. my dataframe is quite big and code is taking quite too much time. I have also tried writing function and apply that but still its too time consuming. Help me to efficient the code.

I have tried using lambda function with apply, i have written a function loop trough it to apply on every row. nothing worked.

```
start= time.time()
df =data_temp['reviews_list'].apply(lambda x :pd.DataFrame(analyser.polarity_scores(x),index=[0]))
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

for initial 100 records its taking 29 seconds. I need a quick solution
also tried

```
def func(x):
    return(analyser.polarity_scores(x))
df =data_temp['reviews_list'].apply(lambda x :pd.DataFrame(func(x),index=[0]))
```

Output should be in form of a dataframe which later i can concat to original dataframe

Comment: the two approaches are essentially the same. Your problem is the function `analyser.polarity_scores()`. Can you provide that function?

Comment: well this is built in function for liberary vader sentiment analyser. I have not written this

Comment: If that's the case, there's little that pandas can do. You could be looking at some parallelization libraries such as numba.

Comment: okay i will check that but however to explain about function is. analyser.polarity_scores() takes a string or sentence as input and output is polarity scores in form of key value object. output is like ({'neg: 0.3,'pos':0.4,'compound': .5})